# remove value list python

Tags: python, list

I want to multiply the values from a list and remove one value, the code is this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
times = 3
start = [1]
visited = [start]
list2 = [n for n in list1 * times]
list2 = 
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

I want list2 to be the list1 multiply 3 times, but removing the value start, when I do this:

```
list2 = [(n for n in list1 * times) - start]
```

give an error, and

```
list2 = [(n for n in list1 * times) != start]
```

removes all the values `start` and I do not want that.

How can I do that the list is multiplicated by a number and then just one valueremoved? The result would be :

```
list2 = [2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

Thank you very much!

**One more thing, [start] in this case is 1, but it could any number present in the list. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove first value from result list that is set in variable start

```
[n for i, n in enumerate(list1*times) if (i < len(list1) and n not in start) or (i >= len(list1))]
```

for

```
start = [1]
```

is result

```
[2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

for

```
start = [2]
```

is result

```
[1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the l2 as follows:

```
l2 = (l1 * 3)[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]

list2 = list1[1:] + list1*2

print (list2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal multiplication operator, then the `list.remove` method:

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> times = 3
>>> start = 1

>>> list2 = list1 * times
>>> list2.remove(start)

>>> list2
[2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
>>>list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>list2 = list1 + list1 + list1
>>>list2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>list2.pop(0)
1
>>>list2
[2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4
```